# Can gRPC response be null? And if that's true, how to check the returned null object?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, protocol-buffers, grpc

Our client side calls a gRPC server, which ideally should return a MyMessage response object.

But can this MyMessage object be null? or gRPC cannot return null object because if it is null, grpc will throw exception.

Suppose the gRPC response is null, then should we check if MyMessage object is null in our client code?

If we do check then we can do:

```
if(MyMessage == null) {
    return;
}


if(MyMessage == null) {
    throw NullPointerException;
}
```

Which one is better? Return or throw exception?

But I don't understand why we need the above null check. Because if the MyMessage object is null, the following call:

```
MyMessge.getName();
```

will throw NullPointerException automatically.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it's not correct (!) to receive a null response to a gRPC method call. gRPC service definitions must take a message and return a message. A null response is an error and the only assumption is that the server failed. Google provides an [`Empty`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Empty) message type in its well-known types. To avoid backwards incompatibility (!), I think it's good practice to define unique request and response messages types for **every** service rather than use `Empty`.

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin, thanks for the comment. So you mean it's possible for a gRPC server side to return a `null`. Then that means in our client side, we should check the response to be not null, since the server may fail. Right? Thanks

Comment: By the way, does gRPC server side throw exception when the response is null? So in the client side we only need to catch that exception instead of checking if the response is null or not.